# URLConnection not returning my image

Tags: android

I am trying to make an URLConnection, but it isn't getting the content of the page.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urlStr = urls[0];
        Bitmap img = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            Log.d("URL", url.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(/*proxy*/);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(20 * 1000);
            Log.d("Before If", "Here");
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.d("After If", "Here");
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        return img;
}
```

The Logcat shows the "Before If: Here", but doesn't show the After one. Why is it wrong? Could it be the URL?
I'm tryinf to access this URL: http://placehold.it/120x120&text=Child%201
It is inside an AsyncTask

Comment: How About printing `urlConnection.getResponseCode()` to the Log to find out what exactly for a problem your experiencing

Answer (score 0):

Ttry using a better image loading library like picasso , UIL etc . . .